# Sonar maven plugin fails to download the JDBC driver

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin, sonarqube

I've started using the sonar maven plugin (and sonar i general). Sonar is installed on another server, and can be successfully accessed in the url http://host:8080/sonar. The configuration in the pom.xml is as follows:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
  <configuration>
    <sonar.host.url>http://host:8080/sonar</sonar.host.url>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Edit**
I've switch the sonar.host.url with sonarHostUrl as well, to no avail.

(I'm still using the 1.0-beta as 2.0 require maven 3 which we haven't switched to yet)

The sonar webapp is configured also with the right properties:

```
sonar.web.host: host
sonar.web.port: 8080
sonar.web.context: /sonar
```

When I run the sonar maven plugin (mvn sonar:sinar) here is the output. It seems that even though I've configured the location properly, the sonar still looks for the default http://localhost:9000/ installation.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://host/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/mojo/sonar-maven-plugin/1.0-beta-2/sonar-maven-plugin-1.0-beta-2.pom
6K downloaded  (sonar-maven-plugin-1.0-beta-2.pom)
Downloading: http://host/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/mojo/sonar-maven-plugin/1.0-beta-2/sonar-maven-plugin-1.0-beta-2.jar
13K downloaded  (sonar-maven-plugin-1.0-beta-2.jar)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Webapp
[INFO]    task-segment: [sonar:sonar] (aggregator-style)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [sonar:sonar {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Sonar host: http://host:8080/sonar
[INFO] Sonar version: 2.8
[INFO] Execute: org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:2.8:sonar
Downloading: http://host/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-maven-plugin/2.8/sonar-maven-plugin-2.8.pom
1K downloaded  (sonar-maven-plugin-2.8.pom)
Downloading: http://host/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar/2.8/sonar-2.8.pom
33K downloaded  (sonar-2.8.pom)
Downloading: http://host/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-maven-plugin/2.8/sonar-maven-plugin-2.8.jar
7K downloaded  (sonar-maven-plugin-2.8.jar)
Downloading: http://host/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-batch/2.8/sonar-batch-2.8.pom
2K downloaded  (sonar-batch-2.8.pom)
Downloading: http://host/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-core/2.8/sonar-core-2.8.pom
3K downloaded  (sonar-core-2.8.pom)
Downloading: http://host/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-plugin-api/2.8/sonar-plugin-api-2.8.pom
6K downloaded  (sonar-plugin-api-2.8.pom)
Downloading: http://host/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-check-api/2.8/sonar-check-api-2.8.pom
736b downloaded  (sonar-check-api-2.8.pom)
Downloading: http://host/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-colorizer/2.8/sonar-colorizer-2.8.pom
1K downloaded  (sonar-colorizer-2.8.pom)
Downloading: http://host/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-channel/2.8/sonar-channel-2.8.pom
1K downloaded  (sonar-channel-2.8.pom)
Downloading: http://host/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-duplications/2.8/sonar-duplications-2.8.pom
1K downloaded  (sonar-duplications-2.8.pom)
Downloading: http://host/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-graph/2.8/sonar-graph-2.8.pom
1K downloaded  (sonar-graph-2.8.pom)
Downloading: http://host/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-squid/2.8/sonar-squid-2.8.pom
2K downloaded  (sonar-squid-2.8.pom)
Downloading: http://host/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-deprecated/2.8/sonar-deprecated-2.8.pom
1K downloaded  (sonar-deprecated-2.8.pom)
Downloading: http://host/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-java-api/2.8/sonar-java-api-2.8.pom
953b downloaded  (sonar-java-api-2.8.pom)
Downloading: http://host/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-batch/2.8/sonar-batch-2.8.jar
126K downloaded  (sonar-batch-2.8.jar)
Downloading: http://host/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-core/2.8/sonar-core-2.8.jar
69K downloaded  (sonar-core-2.8.jar)
Downloading: http://host/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-plugin-api/2.8/sonar-plugin-api-2.8.jar
372K downloaded  (sonar-plugin-api-2.8.jar)
Downloading: http://host/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-check-api/2.8/sonar-check-api-2.8.jar
8K downloaded  (sonar-check-api-2.8.jar)
Downloading: http://host/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-colorizer/2.8/sonar-colorizer-2.8.jar
32K downloaded  (sonar-colorizer-2.8.jar)
Downloading: http://host/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-channel/2.8/sonar-channel-2.8.jar
15K downloaded  (sonar-channel-2.8.jar)
Downloading: http://host/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-duplications/2.8/sonar-duplications-2.8.jar
70K downloaded  (sonar-duplications-2.8.jar)
Downloading: http://host/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-graph/2.8/sonar-graph-2.8.jar
27K downloaded  (sonar-graph-2.8.jar)
Downloading: http://host/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-squid/2.8/sonar-squid-2.8.jar
60K downloaded  (sonar-squid-2.8.jar)
Downloading: http://host/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-deprecated/2.8/sonar-deprecated-2.8.jar
59K downloaded  (sonar-deprecated-2.8.jar)
Downloading: http://host/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-java-api/2.8/sonar-java-api-2.8.jar
8K downloaded  (sonar-java-api-2.8.jar)
[INFO] [sonar:sonar {execution: default-sonar}]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Can not execute Sonar

Embedded error: Fail to download the file: http://localhost:9000/deploy/jdbc-driver.jar (no proxy)
Connection refused: connect
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 33 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jun 01 10:53:33 IDT 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/33M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, my configuration was wrong. You shouldn't have any `<configuration>` inside the plugin definition, but rather a `<properties>` block with the Sonar properties:

```
<properties>
  <sonar.host.url>http://host:8080/sonar</sonar.host.url>
  <sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:mysql://host:3306/sonar</sonar.jdbc.url>
  <sonar.jdbc.username>sonardb</sonar.jdbc.username>
  <sonar.jdbc.password>sonardbpassword</sonar.jdbc.password>
  <sonar.jdbc.driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</sonar.jdbc.driver>
</properties>
```

Thanks to Freddy Mallet for [pointing it out](http://sonar.markmail.org/message/o4ry4cop6o24dorw).

Comment: I think you could use the configuration section if you use sonarHostURL, but I think the properties are better anyway.

Comment: Tried that. The answer is based on the response from the sonar-user mailing list

Answer (score 2):

add in maven settings.xml   the next code:

```
<profile>
        <id>sonar</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <!-- EXAMPLE FOR MYSQL -->
               <sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar</sonar.jdbc.url>
                <sonar.jdbc.driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</sonar.jdbc.driver>
            <sonar.jdbc.username>root</sonar.jdbc.username>
            <sonar.jdbc.password>1234</sonar.jdbc.password>

            <!-- optional URL to server. Default value is http://localhost:9000 -->
            <sonar.host.url>
              http://localhost:9000
            </sonar.host.url>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```